# Flutter ListView pagination from API?

Tags: flutter

Pretty new to flutter. Trying to fit pagination loading from API into existing code but all the resources seem to point towards loading more from a static list.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.placesList.isEmpty
        ? CircularLoadingWidget(height: 200)
        : Container(
            height: 200,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: widget.placesList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                  },
                  child: PlaceCardWidget(place: widget.placesList.elementAt(index)),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
  }
```

I'm a little confused about streams and how to make an endless stream from a paginated API.

```
    getCurrentLocation().then((LocationData _locationData) async {
      final Stream<Place> stream = await getNearPlaces(_locationData, _locationData);
      stream.listen((Place _place) {
        setState(() => placesList.add(_place));
      }, onError: (a) {
        print(a);
      }, onDone: () { print('Places: ' + placesList.length.toString()); });
    });
```

```
Future<Stream<Place>> getNearPlaces(LocationData myLocation) async {
  String _nearParams = '';
  String _orderLimitParam = '';
  if (myLocation != null) {
    _orderLimitParam = 'orderBy=distance&perPage=10';
    _nearParams =
        '&myLon=${myLocation.longitude}&myLat=${myLocation.latitude}';
  }
  final String url = '${GlobalConfiguration().getString('api_base_url')}places/?$_nearParams&$_orderLimitParam';

  final client = new http.Client();
  final streamedRest = await client.send(http.Request('get', Uri.parse(url)));

  return streamedRest.stream
      .transform(utf8.decoder)
      .transform(json.decoder)
      .map((data) => data['results'])
      .expand((data) => (data as List))
      .map((data) {
    return Place.fromJSON(data);
  });
}
```

API format

```
{
    "count": 119,
    "next": "../places/?page=4",
    "previous": "../places/?page=2",
    "results": [],
}
```

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Thanks!